# jQuery: allow user to construct order of a list

Tags: jquery

I have the following list:

```
teams = ['Grizzlies', 'Spurs', 'Warriors', 'Hawks', 'Cavs']
```

This list is passed to the browser allowing the user to select which teams they want to perform an analysis on. I want the user to be able to select one or more of these teams in **whatever order they want**.

For example, if they choose `'Cavs'` first and `'Grizzles'` second the resulting list sent to the server will be `['Cavs', 'Grizzlies']`. Therefore, stuffing these items inside a `<select>` won't do.

I've been searching for a nice, intuitive jQuery plugin that looks nice and permits the functionality I'm looking for. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Someone recommended http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery sortable is a solid option here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/